# How to increment a column value with an increasing number in a csv file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file with 3 columns as below.

```
$ cat test.txt
1,A,300
1,B,300
1,C,300
```

Till now i have tried as, `awk -F, '{$3=$3+1;print}' OFS=, test.txt`

But output is coming as:

```
1,A,301
1,B,301
1,C,301
```

& below is my desired output

Now i want to increment the third column only, the output should be like below

```
1,A,300
1,B,301
1,C,302
```

How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: If any of the following answer helped you in your goal please accept/upvote the answer for closure by ticking right sign besides the answer.

Answer (score 3):

could be, assuming line are sequential like your sample)

```
awk -F ',' '{sub($3"$",$3+NR-1)}7' YourFile
```

it use the line numer as increment value, changing the line end and not the field value (different from an awk POV, that don't need to rebuild the line with separator)

Alternative if empty or other line between modifiable lines (i arbitrary use `NF` as filter but it depend of your criteria if any)

```
awk -F ',' 'NF{sub($3"$",$3+i++)}7' YourFile
```

Comment: What is "7" in this example?

Comment: any number other than 0 will print the current line. 7 is a private joke with some other awk writer

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{x=0;FS=OFS=","} NF>1{$3=$3+x;x++}1' inputfile
1,A,300

1,B,301

1,C,302
```

*Explanation:*

`BEGIN Block` : It contains `x` which is a counter initially set to zero, `FS` and `OFS` . `/./` is used to ignore blank lines(Remove this part if there are no blank lines). `$3=$3+x` : This will add the value of counter to `$3`.  `x++` : To increment the current value of the counter.

Comment: x=0 could be omitted, its 0 by default if used as adding value for unassigned variable. your `x++` could be directly included in `$3=$3+x++`, and `$3=$3+` could be rewrite with `$3+=`. your /./ is also at risk with space line, use maybe a `NF > 1` or `/[^[:blank:]]/`. Your code is correct, do the job so worth the +1

Answer (score 0):

try this NR starts at 1 so NR -1 should give you the correct number

```
 awk -F, '{$3=$3+NR-1;print}' OFS=, test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } ($3+=i++)||1 ' file
```

Comment: Note that this will skip lines where `$3 + i == 0`.

Comment: For a golfed version I would go with: `awk '{$3+=i++} 1' FS=, OFS=,`.

Comment: empty lines have now an `,,3` in my case (sample of OP is ambiguous about space between lines with `,`)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: Right, avoid it by checking for empty lines: `NF {$3+=i++} 1`

Comment: @Thor just learn with your comment that NF is 0 if empty line and not 1 as i supected (1 with empty field value)

Answer (score -1):

awk  'BEGIN{i=0;FS=OFS=","}  NF>1{$3=$3+i;i++}1'  filename

It contains x which is a counter initially set to zero, FS and OFS . /./ is used to ignore blank lines(Remove this part if there are no blank lines).

$3=$3+i : This will add the value of counter to $3. i++ : To increment the value of counter. Must and should give space betwen awk and begin as well as filename and end of the file

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, however, the answer is not readable, can you please format it and add more details?